# OAuth1.0 invalid signature for woocommerce api

Tags: php, android, oauth, woocommerce-rest-api

i followed step by step [wc_api_docs](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http) for authentication over http with oauth1.0a one-legged but the signature of my code either in php or java differ from postmans signature and i face with this error:

> {   "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
>   "message":
>   "Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match.",
>   "data": {
>       "status": 401   } }

```
$url = rawurlencode("http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v1/products");
$ck = rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key").'='.rawurlencode("ck_s6ec05447691a63c76b3ffc575f2f29ba7c0438c");
$nonce = rawurlencode("oauth_nonce").'='.rawurlencode("zNebTNK");
$timestamp = rawurlencode("oauth_timestamp").'='.rawurlencode("1468302526");
$s_method = rawurlencode("oauth_signature_method").'='.rawurlencode("HMAC-SHA256");


$params = rawurlencode($ck."&".$nonce."&".$s_method."&".$timestamp);
$http_method = "GET";

$signature_base = $http_method."&".$url."&".$params;
echo $signature_base.'-------------';
$s = hash_hmac('sha256', $signature_base, 'cs_s70ac550670bdf16e72213855c9745518320e68c', true);
echo urlencode(base64_encode($s));
```

and i cant produce a correct signature, but my postman with this values works correctly!

Comment: If you found solution means, please share it, i'm also facing the same issue.